# Regex for matching multiple forward slashes in URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression for replacing multiple forward slashes in a URL with a single forward slash, excluding the ones following the colon

e.g. `http://link.com//whatever///` would become `http://link.com/whatever/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already accepted an answer. To show some more extend of matching and controlling the matches, this might help you in the future:

```
var url = 'http://link.com//whatever///';
var set = url.match(/([^:]\/{2,3})/g); // Match (NOT ":") followed by (2 OR 3 "/")

for (var str in set) {
    // Modify the data you have
    var replace_with = set[str].substr(0, 1) + '/';

    // Replace the match
    url = url.replace(set[str], replace_with);
}

console.log(url);
```

Will output:

```
http://link.com/whatever/
```

Doublets won't matter in your situation. If you have this string:

```
var url = 'http://link.com//om/om/om/om/om///';
```

Your `set` array will contain multiple `m//`. A bit redundant, as the loop will see that variable a few times. The nice thing is that `String.replace()` replaces nothing if it finds nothing, so no harm done.

What you could do is strip out the duplicates from `set` first, but that would almost require the same amount of resources as just letting the for-loop go over them.

Good luck!

Answer (score 38):

I think this should work: `/[^:](\/+)/` or `/[^:](\/\/+)/` if you want only *multiples*.

It wont match leading `//` but it looks like you're not looking for that.

To replace:

```
"http://test//a/b//d".replace(/([^:]\/)\/+/g, "$1") // -->  http://test/a/b/d
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X6jzs/)**

Comment: When i try to replace the matches with a single forward slash he first one returns http:/link.co/whateve/ and the second one ttp://link.co/whateve/ . For some reason it removes the first preceding character.

Comment: Oh, you want to _replace_ them, and not just _match_ them? That's an important difference.

Comment: @JeffShaver no : it remove some chars

Comment: @dystroy yeah, just saw that

Comment: In your regular expression you don't need the second match group: `/([^:])\/\/+/g` is enough

Comment: yourString.replace(/(https?:\/\/)|(\/)+/g, "$1$2");

Comment: You might instead use a positive lookbehind to only match the `//` and not the prepending character: `(?<=[^:])(\/\/+)`

Answer (score 0):

```
result = subject.replace(/(?<!http:)\/*\//g, "/");
```

or (for http, https, ftp and ftps)

```
result = subject.replace(/(?<!(?:ht|f)tps?:)\/*\//g, "/");
```

Comment: The original question did not ask anything about replacing the scheme. This answer is not relevant.

Comment: @codeadventurer, this regular expression doesn't replace the scheme. This answer is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The original accepted answer does a sufficient job at replacing, but not for matching. And the currently accepted answer matches the character before duplicate slashes, also not good for matching.

Using a negative lookbehind to exclude the protocol from the match `(?<!:)`, and a curly bracket quantifier to match 2 to infinite slashes `\/{2,}` does the job to both match and replace.

```
(?<!:)\/{2,}
```

```js
let str = 'https://test.example.com:8080//this/is//an/exmaple///';
document.write('Original: ' + str + '<br><br>');
document.write('Matches: ' + str.match(/(?<!:)\/{2,}/g) + '<br><br>');
document.write('Replaced: ' + str.replace(/(?<!:)\/{2,}/g, '/'));
```