# remove duplicate forward slashes from the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How can I remove duplicate forward slashes from the a url, but keep the // which comes after `http:` so that the URL does not break.

```
http://localhost//example/author/admin///
```

should be

```
http://localhost/example/author/admin/
```

I'm trying this, but it will remove only the last slash. I want to remove all double

```
abc = 'http://localhost//example/author/admin///';
clean_url = abc.replace(/\/$/,'');
alert(clean_url);
```

The following checks only three slashes.

```
clean_url = abc.replace("///", "");
alert(clean_url);
```

I want to remove all the duplicate slashes.

Comment: I would better work on the URL generation so that one slash cannot follow another one. How are these URLs generated?

Comment: I would fix it at the source - why are these duplicate slashes in the URL to begin with?

Comment: I understand but its quite a long story. I'm trying to use pagination within the tabs. So when you are on a paginated link like something/music/page/6 and you click on other tab, then go to the other page, the URL still have the /page/6 from previous tab, so I need to remove the paginated part from the url when switching the tabs. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Removing multiple forward slashes generally breaks the URL - the new url is not the same as the old one.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use:

```
abc.replace(/([^:]\/)\/+/g, "$1");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X6jzs/)**

**Update:** **[Already answered by Halcyon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15638147/1719752)**

Comment: This does not seem to clean up a string containing just two slashes '//'

Answer (score 9):

*[This question has been answered before...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638104/regex-for-matching-multiple-forward-slashes-in-url)*

```
var str = 'http://localhost//example/author/admin///';    
var clean_url = str.replace(/([^:])(\/\/+)/g, '$1/');

alert(clean_url);
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X6RPb/)

Answer (score 4):

I know there're different answers solving the same problem, just another approach :)

```
var s = "http://www.some-url.com//path//to";
var res = s.replace(/(https?:\/\/)|(\/)+/g, "$1$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Milind Anantwar

I use the following in my Lambda@edge viewer rule to fix duplicate slashes in URL.

```
'use strict';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    // Get request from CloudFront event
    var request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

    // Extract the URI from the request
    var requestUrl = request.uri;

    // Match any duplicate double slashes in URL 
    var redirectUrl = requestUrl.replace(/([^:]\/)\/+/g, "$1");

    // Replace the received URI with the URI that includes the index page
    request.uri = redirectUrl;

    // Return to CloudFront
    return callback(null, request);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

PHP:
To remove extra forward slashes, the below code works fine for me

$path = preg_replace('#/+#', '/', $path);

Comment: That does not look like jQuery after all

Comment: That's PHP Code.