# How to configure Django to redirect multiple slashes (/) to single slash

Tags: python, django

How can I configure my Django project to redirect multiple slashes (symbol `/`) to a single slash?

For example, I want to issue a `HTTP response code 301 redirect` for this URL

```
https://mywebsite.com/path//to//id///
```

and redirect it to:

```
https://mywebsite.com/path/to/id/
```

How could that be done?

Comment: this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638104/regex-for-matching-multiple-forward-slashes-in-url

Comment: What WSGI server are you using? Production hosting mechanisms such as Apache/mod_wsgi will collapse such repeating slashes in paths and you will never see them, thus you don't need to have special handling for them.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton , is it possible to issue 301 redirect in such cases? I'm using Apache/mod_wsgi. I want 301 redirect from example.com///////////// to example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django 2: using re_path

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#re-path

```
from django.urls import re_path

re_path(r'^bar/(?P<foo>[/\w]+)/$', views.bio, name='bio' ),
```