# How to configure Apache to avoid redirecting of multiple slashes (/) to single slash

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

This question is related to [How to configure Django to redirect multiple slashes (/) to single slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51228796/how-to-configure-django-to-redirect-multiple-slashes-to-single-slash#comment112738485_51228796)

I use Apache/mod_wsgi and I want 301 redirect instead of Apache just removing the slashes.

Answer (score 1):

This situation is simple to resolve using a tasty slice of .htaccess.

All you need to do is copy the following code and place it anywhere in your site's root .htaccess file:

```
   # Remove double or triple forward slashes
   <IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 301 ^///?(.*)$ http://example.com/$1
   </IfModule>
```

For Example:

```
 *  http://example.com// redirects to http://example.com/
 *  http://example.com//blog-post/ redirects to http://example.com/blog-post/
 *  http://example.com//path/directory/ redirects to http://example.com/path/directory/
```

I got the answer from this [blog](https://htaccessbook.com/remove-double-forward-slashes/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache can't you simply do this with mod_alias

i.e. (where foo.bar is your domain)

```
# Remove multiple forward slashes
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 301 ^//+(.*)$ https://foo.bar/$1
</IfModule>
```